Jockey wheels rattling noise
I've just replaced my rear derailleur with a new one Shimano Ultegra RD8000 and even before buying I noticed some users reporting that jockey wheels are hardly moving on brand new rd8000 and so was mine, wheels are not stuck but they are not spinning freely like they did on previous derailleur (rd6800).
I've bought a new chain as well since rear cassette was changed but this should be cause of load noise comming from rear derailleur.
I noticed that if my cadance is higher so is the noise and it sounds like rattling/clicking noise coming from jockey wheels.
So my question is should I just lube the bearings inside jockey wheels or buy a new set of them? Should jockey wheels be spinning freely or not?
I lubricated jockey wheels from the old derailleur with all purpose bike grease (Motox), but jockey wheels are now not spinning as they did before?
Should I go and buy another grease/lube for them or can I just use dry chain lube?
Thanks for the help and guidance.

It sounds like you just discovered that grease is viscous. In old jockey wheels the grease has settled outside the bearing track or completely evaporated so they spin freely, and it takes a while before the grease in new bearings settles. I would ride the new derailleur for a while, and think about using thinner grease if the problem doesn't disappear after a hundred kilometers or so.

Could be, I considered that jockeys need break-in period. Noted I only did a short 40km ride so far, but I wanted to check if this is common, expected (break-in period) or something I should be worried about.

If you believe that power loss of the jockey wheels should be minimal, maybe you should consider replacing the jockey wheels with ones having ball bearings on both jockey wheels.
Note that in Shimano derailleurs, the two wheels are different. The top guide pulley is a Centeron pulley, having side-to-side wobble. The bottom tension pulley is not a Centeron pulley.
I have never understood why Shimano decided to use Centeron pulleys for the top guide pulleys. Maybe it improves performance with poor derailleur adjustment, but then again if you have good parts (not the cheapest Tourney parts), good cabling and good adjustment, a non-wobbly bearing would work well too.
For example Tacx manufactures ball bearing pulleys for both guide and tension pulleys.

Boths jockeys are already have ball bearings, I believe Shimano replaced Centreron a while ago and now both have ball bearings inside. Previous version had also both of jockeys with ball bearings.

Click shifting Shimano (and I would presume others) have always had lateral play in the jockey wheel to assure perfect alignment since you cannot trim them manually.
